Подтверждение что есть 18 на javascript
Опишу ситуацию, я начинающий вебмастер в верстке сайтов почти год. Умею прописывать на html и css.
Создал сайт-магазин в котором разные категории товаров , включая 18+. Но товары для взрослых я не добавлял т.к. юрист сказал мне, что должно всплывать окно подтверждения возраста и до подтверждения возраста товары не должны быть видны.
Я знаю что такое делается на JavaScript, но у меня минимальные знанию по этому языку, ни разу сам ничего не прописывал, только поверхностное знание что это такое.
Подскажите пожалуйста как такое сделать.
Нужно чтобы переходя на любую из страниц с товаром для взрослых, новый пользователь  не мог увидеть товар пока не нажмет "да" при подтверждении возраста. А если нажмет "нет" то вернется на главную страницу сайта или покинет сайт.

if (confirm('Вам есть 18?')) {} else {}

Вешаете слушатель на "ссылку" и задаете вопрос пользователю стандартным браузерным confirm(в идеале заменить на собственную модалку) и проверяете, что ответил пользователь:


// Выбираем в DOM элемент с ID = link и вешаем слушатель события
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (confirm('Вам уже есть 18 лет?')) {
    //window.location.href = './18yearsold' // Переход в нужный раздел
    alert('Добро пожаловать')
  } else {
    alert('Вам сюда нельзя')
  }
})
<div id="link">
  Скрытая категория товаров
</div>



